# Problem filling a DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am trying to fill out a DataGridView with data from a database. The program is a test from an runs fine. There is a single table called Animals. The line "using (SqlCeDataAdapter a = new SqlCeDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Animals", c))" fails if I change Animals to something else, so it definitely reads the table. But nothing is shown in the DataGridView. No column names and no data, just an empty grey. What am I missing?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            FillData();
        }

        void FillData()
        {
            using (SqlCeConnection c = new SqlCeConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.DataConnectionString))
            {
                c.Open();
                using (SqlCeDataAdapter a = new SqlCeDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Animals", c))
                {
                    DataTable t = new DataTable();
                    a.Fill(t);
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = t;
                }
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you make sure you are getting any data filled in that `DataTable`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dataGridView1.DataBind();
```

Add it after giving the source to your grid and it should work.

Comment: It says that 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' does not contain a definition for 'DataBind' :-(

Comment: Uh sorry, have you debugged and saw that your table has values?

Comment: If so, make sure that dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = True

Comment: When I open Server Explorer and right-click on the table, then I can see the 4 rows of data I typed in manually. Do I have to save the table edits seperately?

Comment: Excellent! dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = True worked. Super. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

dataGridView1.DataBind()

and also make sure that Gridview autogenerate column property is set to true.